# show that inverses $\pi_{1},\pi_{2}$ are recursive?

Tags: logic, computability

show that one can define inverses $\pi_{1},\pi_{2}$ for $ \langle.,.\rangle$ with$\pi_{1}(\langle m,n \rangle)=m,\pi_{2}(\langle m,n \rangle)=n\ \   
\forall n,m$ wich are also recursive?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Comment: What is the definition of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$? Is it some pairing function, or is it just the ordered pair? Or what?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would guess is Cantor's pairing function.

Comment: yes it is pairing function

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ means the Cantor pairing function.)

**HINT:** If $\langle m,n\rangle=k$ then $m,n\leq k$.

Comment: i coud not undrestand. why $m,n<k$

Comment: That's why this is a hint. You should prove that, then (judging by your other question), the solution will be easy enough.

Comment: You don't really need a bound, as long as $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is computable then given $k$ you can just search for the unique $m,n$ with $k = \langle m,n \rangle$.